# How to make proxying const/ref/volatile qualification without duplication in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++23

Say I want to write some "proxy" object for a callable, e.g. to add some feature that happens before the wrapped callable is invoked. Further, say I want to be const-correct, so that the proxy has an accessible non-const `operator()` only if the wrapped callable does. Then I need to do something like this, defining two versions of the operator and using SFINAE:

```cpp
template <typename F>
struct Proxy {
  F wrapped;
  
  template <typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F&>>>
  auto operator()();
  
  template <typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<const F&>>>
  auto operator()() const;
};
```

This is annoying enough, but if I also want to proxy ref qualifications now I need for overloads, which is really getting excessive. Heaven help me if I also want to proxy `volatile` qualfiication.

Is there a shortcut to make this less awful? I seem to recall there was at least a feature proposed for addition to the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed feature I was thinking of was [P0847R7](https://wg21.link/P0847R7) ("Deducing `this`"), which was [accepted for C++23](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/5002). There are some useful slides [here](https://corecppil.github.io/Meetups/2020-10-28_CoreCpp_Std_Oct/P0847-Deducing-this.pdf). I don't have a compiler to check this with, but I believe my four operators could be written as one with something like the following:

```cpp
template <typename F>
struct Proxy {
  F wrapped;
  
  template <typename Me>
      requires std::invocable<std::like_t<Me, F>>
  auto operator()(this Me&& me);
};
```

(The type requirement here uses the hypothetical [`like_t`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html#proposal) metafunction assumed by P0847R7. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71404906/1505451).)

Comment: "*I don't know the status of that proposal.*" It has been adopted by C++23, but no compiler has implemented it yet.

Comment: Awesome! Can I ask where I could have looked that up? In other words, could you cite a reference?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: I meant the status of the paper (accepted/not), but I see that page works for that too. Thanks!

Comment: The status of the paper: https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/115