# In C++ is there a proposed type traits helper for "copying" reference category and cv-qualification?

Tags: c++, type-traits, c++23

For the SFINAE in the hypothetical call operator in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71404857/1505451) I need a type trait that "copies" reference category and const/volatile qualifications from one type to another:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
using copy_category_and_qualifications_t = [...];

copy_category_and_qualifications_t<int, char>             // char
copy_category_and_qualifications_t<const int&, char>      // const char&
copy_category_and_qualifications_t<volatile int&&, char>  // volatile char&&
```

I seem to recall some proposed addition to `type_traits` for this. Does anybody have a reference to this proposal, or know if it was added for C++20 or C++23?

Comment: Don't you mean the [`like_t`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r6.html#proposal) mentioned in the *Deducing this*? As the paper says, "*This proposal assumes the existence of two library additions, though it does not propose them.*” That is to say, there are no such type_triats in C++20/C++23 (at least for now).

Comment: Yes! I guess that paper is where I heard about it in the first place; I didn't re-read the whole thing while writing that answer. Thank you. If you submit that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[P1450](https://wg21.link/p1450) called this `copy_cvref` and `clone_cvref` (the former just applies the qualifiers to the 2nd parameter, the latter first removes the qualifiers from the 2nd parameter). The former is useful, I don't think I've ever personally had a need for the latter.

[P0847](https://wg21.link/p0847) uses `like_t` and `forward_like` in a few contexts, `like_t` there is basically P1450's `copy_cvref` (the latter is... a significantly better name). `forward_like` is separately proposed in [P2445](https://wg21.link/p2445) (though without the other type trait helper).

Comment: It is worth noting that the standard also uses type traits similar to `copy_cvref` in the calculation of `common_reference`, namely [`XREF` and `COPYCV`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/meta#trans.other-2.3).

Comment: What's the status of P1450 (and how do I find this out for a paper in general)? Was it accepted for C++23?

Comment: Ah, it sounds from [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/216#issuecomment-1253054869) that it is being considered for C++26.